# Apache POI - getStringCellValue() value inconsistent

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI's `getStringCellValue()` to try and read and obtain a data from an xlsx file. Depending on the data, I will then proceed to do different things.

If it matters, I'm also using `cellIterator` to iterate through the cells for each row.

As the full code is complex(and formatting with regards to tab on SO kind of sucks), this is a summarized version:

```
Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = Row.cellIterator();

while(cellIterator.hasNext()){
   Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
   theColumnIndex = cell.getColumnIndex();
   
   switch (theColumnIndex) {
      case 0:
        String value = cell.getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        //.....do more stuffs...
        break;

      case 1:
        //...etc...
   }
}
```

Why does the return data for `getStringCellValue()` wildly vary for the same type of cell? I'm trying to read a (seemingly?) blank/null/empty/nothing cell and sometimes it skips reading the cell, yet other times it reads the cell as having a valid value.

Using the sample code above, sometimes `Hello World` gets printed, sometimes it doesn't, depends on the blank cell being read, the factors which causes it being an enigma to me.

For the most part, I'm expecting any blank cell to skip the entire portion (ie. `Hello World` **doesn't** get printed)

### Edit

Attempts at reviewing Apache POI's `Row` definition, these is what I see and compiled(column D in my data file is one of the columns that may or may not be a blank cell depending on the row):

```
 <main:c r="D5" s="5"/>
 <main:c r="D6" s="5"/>
 <D15 does not exist?>
 <D17 does not exist?>
 <main:c r="D19" s="30"/>
 <main:c r="D22"/>
```

From what I'm understanding, regardless whether the cell is blank or not, if it is defined as above in the respective `Row` object, it will be read. Row 15 and Row 17 didn't have their Column D defined, so they're not read.

Reading through [the](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) [documentations](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html), they're very vague on how the cell is "defined"(I have blank cells with the 'Clear All Format' option chosen that is still defined), which I presume to result in above.

Comment: You do different stuff depending on column index, not depending of cell type. Thus, every time you are in column A, `System.out.println("Hello World");` is called regardless

Comment: See [Iterate over rows and cells -> Iterate over cells, with control of missing / blank cells](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator): "The CellIterator will **only** return the cells defined in the file, which is largely those with values or stylings, but it depends on Excel".

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I dont think you understood the question. When reading a blank cell, sometimes ```cell.getStringCellValue();``` literally ignores everything else after it (ie. it doesnt print ```Hello World```), sometimes it continues on, printing out ```Hello World```. My issue is why does it happen; what value is being read that causes it to continue on to print ```Hello World``` while other times it doesnt. Im reading a literally blank cell and have seen both outputs happen.

Comment: That is not what your title or your question are about really. You are mostly saying that `cell.getStringCellValue();` is "broken" for you

Comment: "they're very vague on how the cell is "defined"": The vagueness is not Apache POI's fault. It is Microsoft Excel what decides whether cells are stored  or not. And that decision is such vague. If created using Apache POI, all cells you create using `Row.createCell` **are** stored. So that's not vague.

Comment: @AxelRichter the datafile was created using Excel, not Apache POI. The cell is read if it has values or formatting(as mentioned, my blank cell has neither) and that still depends on Excel. Did I mention my blank cell which is cleared of all formatting and has no values is still defined in the ```Row``` object? I feel like that would be the definition of "vague".

Comment: @Erik So ring your Microsoft account manager and report a bug in Excel? Apache POI is giving you what's in the file, any craziness from Excel is Excel's fault...

Answer (score 3):

The method [`getStringCellValue`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getStringCellValue--)  throws an Exception if the cell is not holding a `String` or a formula returning a string:

> Get the value of the cell as a string
> **For numeric cells we throw an exception**. For blank cells we return an empty string. **For formulaCells that are not string Formulas, we throw an exception**.

You should use [`getCellType`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCellType--) to know the if the cell is empty or not and eventually you know the right type of the holded value:

> Return the cell type.

It returns a [`CellType`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType.html) with one the following possible values:

- _NONE
- BLANK
- ERROR
- FORMULA
- NUMERIC
- STRING

Comment: As mentioned in the OP post, the documentation is vague on how the cells are "defined", so there has been cases whether attempting to do what you're suggesting will fail, because it wont run in the first place. One thing I can at least think of though, is to use your suggestion as an additional checking to at least minimise the issue.

Comment: See also https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator for how to have more control over missing and empty cells